# How to iterate through an SQL table which "parent" and child" rows are in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In a table there are the columns ID, Title and ParentID. ParentID is used for the ID of the entry in the same table which is considered its parent - thus any entry in which ParentID is NULL is one which is itself a parent.

I need a query which will iterate through each parent and list any child below it (ideally with a hyphen or something to denote its subordination) does anyone know how this can be done or how to point me in the right direction?

(I've looked into T-SQL and read many similar online questions however my SQL isn't quite sharp enough to make sense of it, so I'd greatly appreciate some pointers!)

Comment: in oracle - this is a CONNECT BY - maybe that gives sql-server clues.. not sure

Comment: If you really want to iterate through a table, write a query and read it with a cursor. But I assume, that you want to have a query which returns a row with its child rows. Am I right?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx  CTE/recursive queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are!

```
WITH n(ID, Title) AS 
                    (SELECT ID, Title
                    FROM YourTable
                    WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM YourTable WHERE ParentID IS NULL)
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT nplus1.ID, nplus1.Title
                    FROM YourTable as nplus1, n 
                    WHERE n.ID = nplus1.ParentID) 
                    SELECT ID, Title FROM n
```

Answer (score 1):

To get hierarchy data from self-referencing table, you can use WITH syntax in sql 2008

```
  WITH n(ID) AS 
   (SELECT ID FROM YourTable 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT nplus1.ID
   FROM YourTable as nplus1, n 
   WHERE n.ID = nplus1.ParentID) 
   SELECT ID FROM n
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! I didn't explain something well though: ideally, it should list the Title of the first parent (where ParentID is null) then list the Titles of that parent's children (ideally prepended with a hyphen, for example)