# How to find Parents and Children in a same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to find parents and children in the below table. I tried with below query. But it throws the error

> [Err] 1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &
>   IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

I need to find all parents until it reply null. Please help me to find that.

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM categories 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE parentid IS NULL LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT cat.id, cat.name
FROM categories as cat,
     categories 
WHERE categories.id = cat.parentid
```

[image]

`

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY?

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output

Comment: You need to do a LEFT JOIN for every relation...You might want to consider to drop the "Adjacency List" Model (parent id model) for a better model like "Nested Set" Model or "Closure Table" Model.. read http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @jarlh I can't use order by because that all UUID

Comment: @Mittal I need to list like parent->sub-parent->children if it is null, then start again  parent->sub-parent->children

Comment: using UUID is pretty wastfull why you didn't use a AUTO_INCREMENT id?

Comment: Why LIMIT at all? Especially when no order by is used...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm working in a Existing code and that id mapped with other tables. So I can't do anything with that id

Comment: @jarlh I just follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720717/how-to-iterate-through-an-sql-table-which-parent-and-child-rows-are-in-same-t , I can remove that Limit

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just visited that side you gave me, That is awesome. I'm gonna try that. Thank for your help

Comment: Check [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Are you walking up (or down) a tree?  What version are you using?  Does it have CTEs?  If not, upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by below query: This query display all the child with it's parent name. This results in multiple rows.

```
SELECT child.id
    ,child.NAME
    ,parent.NAME
FROM categories AS parent
LEFT JOIN categories AS child ON child.parentid = parent.Id
```

Order by can be this way, but didn't tested

```
SELECT child.id
    ,child.NAME
    ,parent.NAME
FROM categories AS parent
LEFT JOIN categories AS child ON child.parentid = parent.Id
ORDER BY coalesce(parent.id, child.id)
    ,parent.id IS NOT NULL
    ,child.id
```

Comment: It works dude, Can I append the Null categories too? I mean, the first one is SHAWL and it's null so I can list that first, then move to second(OFFER) if it is null we can show that also and move to next.. when the 'Electronics' comes, it starts to find that's sub-parents and children

Comment: USe the left join to allow the category which doesn't have any child... Please the updated answer

Comment: sorry for that miss understanding, If I can display all parent_id, I can just pass that in the code and get all related products. Thanks for your all replies. God Bless